# Problemas con Sms Receiver Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sms

tengo un problema extraño ya que el SMS Receiver es ignorado por teléfonos de la marca Samsung (lo probé con el modelo Note 8 y otro mas que no recuerdo cual era). Lo que sucede es que estos teléfonos cuando reciben un mensaje es como si ignoraran, he probado la aplicación en otras marcas como Sony y la verdad anduvo muy bien. Les deje el código para ver si alguien me puede orientar. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static SmsListener mListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

    for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){

        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);


        String numeroEmisor = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress(); // TRAE EL NUMERO DEL REMITENTE SMS
            String cuerpoDelMensaje = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERBOCY DE SMS RECEIVER " + cuerpoDelMensaje);
            mListener.messageReceived(cuerpoDelMensaje,numeroEmisor);



    }
}

public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

}
```

}

**el Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider" />


<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/motologin_icon"
    android:label="@string/nombre_app"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--  <activity
          android:name=".LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
        >-->
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

</application>
```

**y el mainActivity Esta en la parte de oncreate.**

```
        SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {   ///actua cada vez que ingresa un nuevo SMS a la bandeja de entrada
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(String cuerpoDelMensaje,String numeroEmisor) {
            int iniciolatitud, finlatitud, iniciolongitud, finlongitud, finlongitudS = 0;
            String longitud = "";
            String latitud = "";

            if (numeroEmisor.equals(getString(R.string.numeroemisorGPS)) ) {    // consulto que el numero de emisor que quiero se encuentre en la bandeja de entrada y tomo la partes del mensaje que me interesan.
                iniciolatitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("lat:") + 4;
                finlatitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("long");
                iniciolongitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("long") + 5;
                finlongitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf(",T:");
                finlongitudS = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("speed");
                if (finlongitudS > finlongitud) {
                    latitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitudS);
                } else if ((finlongitudS < finlongitud)) {
                    latitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitud);
                }
                if (iniciolatitud > 4) {
                    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=17");
                    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                    //          } });
                    Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=16");
                    //   Log.e("ya viene",""+latitud);
                    Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");

                }else { //EN CASO DE QUE EL MENSAJE NO SEA EL DE ACTUALIZAR EL MAPA, MOSTRARÁ DICHO SMS EN UNA VENTANA EMERGENTE
                    TextView txtmensaje;
                    Button btnFollow;
                    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sms_popup);
                    txtmensaje = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmensaje);
                    txtmensaje.setText(cuerpoDelMensaje);
                    btnFollow = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfollow);
                    btnFollow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    myDialog.show();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //OCULTO  EL PROGRESSBAR
                textBuscando.setAlpha(0); //OCULTO LA IMAGEN Y TEXTO DEL PROGRESSBAR
            }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Revisaste la version de android de estos dispositivos? a partir de la v7 se pone un poco restrictivo , ya en android 8, es terrible...

Comment: Muchas gracias @LcsGrz, voy a seguir investigando a ver de donde viene el problema, cualquier cosa comparto la solución

Comment: Lee esta documentacion :D https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#java